# Can I safely turn a standard computer PSU into a 220VAC to 36VDC converter?

Tags: power-supply, ac-dc, piezoelectricity

I'm a mostly electronics noob, and wanting to be safe.  I am wanting to build my own fog machine, using some piezoelectric discs that I believe work best with 36v (I'm guessing this from looking at the specs of one that is quite expensive).  What I'm thinking I should be able to do is take a computer PSU, which has 12vDC outputs for the fans on the computer, and wire up 3 of those outputs in serial to generate a 36vDC output for the discs.

My main concern related to doing this is safety -- I'll get a reasonable quality PSU unit, so I'm thinking it should have a circuit breaker / etc... in it to prevent it from overheating / exploding / etc....  Does that sound right?  Any other safety issues I should be worried about?  (is 36v from a computer PSU enough to be significantly dangerous, for example, if I touch the wires -- I'll be careful not to of course, but wondering what level of concern I should have in all this.)

Thanks much for any tips / suggestions -- I've had a hard time finding a 220vAC to 36vDC converter for any kind of reasonable price.

Cheers,
Kem

Comment: think about this ... using a 12 V battery, connect 3 wires to the positive terminal, connect 3 wires to the negative terminal ... can you get 36 V by connecting the wires in series?

Comment: You need three separate PSUs do do this and you need to break the ground connection and float them from each other. Just get yourself a 36 V PSU amd save yourself the hassle.

Comment: Maximum voltage you can get is 24V. Voltage between +12 and -12

Comment: You can get a good-quality 36 V DC PSU for a fair price, e.g. [Mean Well Embedded Switch Mode Power Supply SMPS, 36V dc, 2.8A, 100.8W Enclosed](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/embedded-switch-mode-power-supplies-smps/1065847). This is not a recommendation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't work. Many PSUs have a single 12 volt rail (all of the yellow wires are connected together). Even if you find a PSU with multiple 12 volt rails, it still won't work because all of the black return wires are connected together.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY7d90.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here's a representation of what you want to do with a 3-rail power supply. Observe that because all of the 0V wires are internally interconnected, you've managed to short out the #2 and #3 +12 volt outputs.

Comment: Thanks much for the detailed schematic, it makes a lot of sense :)

Answer (score 9):

No - it's not doable.

The computer PSUs typically have a single 12V output rail, and so all 12V outputs are in parallel.

You can't connect 12V outputs in series to make a 36V supply, you would short out the supply.

Comment: Even with 3 PSUs, the 0V is typically earthed and so you can’t connect them in series.

Comment: @Frog Actually, earthed or not, all of the common (black) wires are connected together.

Comment: @DoxyLover I think he means 3 separate ATX power supply units. Even that would not work as the grounds (black wires) are earthed.

Comment: @Unimportant Some people defeat the earth connection on supplies to be able to do that. So definitely possible with multiple modified PSUs. But it's unsafe. And this question I interpreted to just use single PSU.

Comment: thanks much for your help and all the comments, they've been very helpful, and I have a much better understanding of my problem now :)

Answer (score 3):

If you apply 36VDC to a piezoelectric disc, nothing useful will happen (the disc will change its dimension slightly due to the DC but that's all). I'm assuming you want the disc to vibrate. This requires an AC signal. You need to provide more information as to what you are trying to do to get a better response.

Comment: I think this should have been a comment rather than an answer. The issue of driving piezoelectric discs is not really the question here.

Comment: Thanks Barry, this points out an issue I hadn't realized, I was expecting it to work -- I guess I really just want a 220vac to 36vac transformer -- I want the discs to vibrate in order to generate mist.